# Djangoのソルト値について

Tags: django

パスワードのハッシュ化時、ソルト値に何を使用してるのか知りたいです。

ソース追ってみたのですが、分かりませんでした。
setting.pyのSECRET-KEYではなかろうかと思っているのですが…

どなたか教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0):

hasher次第だけどここらへんじゃないかな。
https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/utils/crypto.py#L48-L69

乱数生成器の内部状態、時刻、SECRET_KEYの組み合わせから生成されたSHA256を種とする12桁のランダム英数。

Comment: ernixさん　お返事が遅くなりました。まだデバッグ出来てないのですが、早々にユーザー登録時、get_random_stringでソルト値生成が行われているか追ってみたいと思います。